# jQuery this form input

Tags: jquery, forms, input, this

I'm having problems getting the form input when passing "this" form into the form processing function.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return process_feedback(this);">
    <input name="ItemID" type="hidden" value="123" />
    <input name="Submit 1" type="submit" value="Submit" />123
</form>

<form onsubmit="return process_feedback(this);">  
    <input name="ItemID" type="hidden" value="234" />
    <input name="Submit 2" type="submit" value="Submit" />234
</form>

<form onsubmit="return process_feedback(this);">  
     <input name="ItemID" type="hidden" value="345" />
     <input name="Submit 3" type="submit" value="Submit" />345
 </form>

<div id="FormSubmitStatus"></div>
```

javascript:

```
function process_feedback(form) {

    var ItemID = $('form:input[name="ItemID"]').val();

    $('#FormSubmitStatus').html("You submitted the form for ItemID " + ItemID);

    return false;

}
```

All i'm getting back from the ItemID variable is "undefined". http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/GV3Z6/

Any help greatly appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the form object as the context for the selector. For instance:

```
function process_feedback(form) {

    var ItemID = $('input[name="ItemID"]', form).val();

    $('#FormSubmitStatus').html("You submitted the form for ItemID " + ItemID);

    return false;

}
```

See the [jQuery selector context documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) for more information.

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't know you could do that.....another thing to learn. I seem to find it really difficult using the jQuery documentation to find useful things like this.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Dan's original selector: 'form:input[name="ItemID"]' was returning an empty list because the ':input' notation is a filter, and means something different than 'form input[name="ItemID"]' which actually looks for input tags within a form.

Comment: Also, in an effort to apply random things that I've read, according to this article: http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-advanced-jquery-performance-tuning-tips-from-paul-irish you get slightly better performance when you use $(form).find('input[name="ItemID"]').

Comment: @MichaC That'd be correct since the internal implementation of the selector with context method is to call $(context).find(selector). It's a +1 function call.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/felixcriv/thTVp/10/